# Qt5, MSVC2010 rebuilds every time, deletes *.obj on “DLL-link-fail”

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, build

I use `QMake` to gen `*.vcproj` (from `*.pro`) to create DLLs that expose C++ classes to QML (Qt5.0.1/MSVC2010).  The DLLs work.

However, I have two problems (they might be related):

1. When I "build", it ALWAYS recompiles everything in the DLL.  (It's never "up-to-date".)
2. If I get a "link-fail" (for example, some input lib doesn't have a needed-function defined), MSVC will delete all the `*.obj` and other intermediate files, requiring the *next* build to (unnecessarily) rebuild those intermediates.  (The "link-success" will LEAVE the intermediate `*.obj` files, but the next build will force them to be regenerated anyway.)  This means I can never do a *"Project Only => Link Only"* when I fix an "input-static-lib".

Both of these seem weird.  And, they make me sad.

Note that since I "regenerate" the `.vcproj` each time, there are no "files-in-the-project" that do not exist on disk (which others observe as a cause to always-trigger-rebuild).

I've already tried the "silly-stuff" like re-installing service packs, clean builds, manually removing all intermediates/artifacts, reboot, etc.

From web searches (lots of reading for weeks to get around this), this might be related to:

- Each DLL has its own directory for its "intermedate-OBJs", but they all write to the same (shared-debug)-"output" folder for their `.dll/.lib`.  (That should be fine, right?)

Failing a "proper-fix" (where MSVC realizes that things are up-to-date), is there a work-around where I can *suppress* the delete-intermediate-files so I can later force a mere "re-link", when *I know* that things should be fine?  At present, I can't *"Project Only => Link Only"* because the intermediates get deleted.  (How to stop MSVC from deleting the `.obj` files?)

Comment: Is it making `.bsc` files in your solution directory?

Comment: @Qix, no, only `.ncb` and `.suo` in solution directory.